# What do you call the term for a made up word composed from two different languages?

Tags: single-word-requests

Testing a child's language proficiency he answered "Swimar", when asked to say swim in Spanish (the correct answer would have been nadar)

Comment: So, was this a kid who was just making stuff up to "sound" Spanish? There are a lot of examples of people saying English words and putting -o on the end of them just to make it "sound" Spanish.

Comment: Huh?  Fairly obviously "this" kid, perhaps the child of the parent asking, has been raised in a bilingual environment -- the phenomenon described is common, and cool.

Comment: How is that obvious? It could be a kid who's learning Spanish and is taking an oral exam but can't think of the word in Spanish, so he said the English word with the Spanish ending.

Answer (score 3):

> They are hybrid words.
>
> **[A hybrid word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_word#Common_hybrids)** is a word which etymologically has one part derived from one language and another part derived from a different
>   language.
>
> The most common form of hybrid word in English is one which combines
>   etymologically Latin and Greek parts. (wiki)

Comment: But a hybrid word, is an actual word.  (Such as automobile or television.)  This is unrelated to actual words. The OP is (I BELIEVE) seeking the term for the common phenomenon where deeply bilingual children, of a certain age, sometimes "mix up" words (forming a nonsense), as in the example.

Comment: @JoeBlow..sure, thanks for bringing it up. I looked at the post header and answered.

Answer (score 2):

You could call it **Spanglish**, which [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanglish) defines as "an overlapping and mixing of Spanish and English lexical items and grammar." One aspect of Spanglish mentioned is that English words are turned into Spanish verbs, such as *faxear* (to fax) and *lonchar* (to have lunch).

Comment: Note Spanglish is a portmanteau, though unfortunately of two English words and as such, not an example of Spanglish itself.  If only it were "Espanglish..."

Comment: Spanish speakers (like me) say "Espanglish". I've also heard _Inglañol_.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [pidgin](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pidgin#pidgin_1) Spanish to me.

Comment: Hi Tim.  I interpreted the question as very obviously referring to the (extremely common) thing done by children raised in truly bi- or multi-lingual environments where they do, well, exactly as in the example given.  It's never occurred to me that there might be a term for this (in some language!) .. surely there is such a term.

Comment: @JoeBlow To me, it seems like Tim's answer is a good match for what you (and the OP) just described, saving only that it describes a whole language and not a single word.  Maybe *pidgin word*?

Comment: @JoeBlow: Do you think that only children do this?

Comment: Hi Tim.  Funnily enough I did this once (I mean as an adult) - in Germany I insist on calling a certain drink "apple-shafter" which is a sort of stupid mix-up of English and German bits.  But surely you see the difference between "an adult does it occasionally" and "that phenomenon that billingual kids do."

Comment: @Joe|: I am not sure I agree that there is a clear dividing line. But if the child *is* systematically (accidentally) mingling two languages, that is the definition of a pidgin (or possibly a creole, but let's leave that for the moment). This muight be worth taking to chat.

Comment: The trouble is "pidgin" is a language, pidgin words are real words.  This is just the child accidentally saying a nonsense word (but in "two languages - how cute").